# how script tag loaded in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, webpack

I am trying to understand this repo https://github.com/gothinkster/angular-realworld-example-app but i dont understand why the index file :

https://github.com/gothinkster/angular-realworld-example-app/blob/master/src/index.html

does not have any script tag but when i start with server script tag still loaded in html response. Do you have any idea for this?

Comment: That's the source. Whatever you are running is the compiled. Compiled index.html will be injected script tags appropriately.

Comment: That repo is based on angular-cli project that uses webpack. So webpack but more precisely `HtmlWebpackPlugin` does all work https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/%40angular/cli/models/webpack-configs/browser.ts#L65-L76

Comment: if i want custom config for my project how can i do that, did you have any suggest or sample project that you used before. Thank so much @yurzui

Comment: With angular-cli you get all you need. If you want to have a custom config just run `ng eject` or create your own boilerplate for angular project